# Hotels with or around casinos in Colombo

Tags: hotels, sri-lanka, colombo

I am hoping to visit Colombo in a couple weeks and I am looking to stay in a hotel (at least 4 star user ratings).

I expect to spend quite a bit of time at casinos in Colombo and based on my past experience in Goa (India), if I don't reside close enough to a casino, I spend a lot of money in taxis just commuting back and forth.

I am hoping to avoid this in Colombo.

1. If I do find a hotel I like in Colombo but one that is far away from casinos, will I be spending a fair bit commuting in taxis?
2. I realise that recommendations may be beyond the scope of this site but is it reasonable to expect to be in a central, scenic and casino rich area of Colombo and if so, what hotels would you recommend in such an area?

Comment: Colombo is totally changed now. Everything is now became easier than the last decade. You can book varieties of hotels around srilanka. Uber/Pickme taxi services are available and many more changes happened in the recent years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend the Galle Face Hotel.   This is less than 4kms from these casinos:-

- Ballagio Casino
- Marino Casino
- MGM Casino

If you are staying at a 4 star hotel and spending lots of time at the casino, the cost of a taxi or auto-rickshaw over 4km is going to be minimal in comparison.